# не могу создать python3 manage.py makemigrations

Tags: python, django

не могу создать/применить миграции,  выдает ошибку

```
    from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
User = get_user_model()
#settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
#*******
#1 Category
#2 Product
#3 CartProduct
#4 Cart
#5 Order
#*************
#6 Customer
#7 Specification


class Category(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Имя категории')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.name


class Product(models.Model):

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name='Категория', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Наименование')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Изображение')
    description = models.TextField(verbose_name='Описание', null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Цена')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class CartProduct(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey('Customer', verbose_name='Покупатель', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ForeignKey('Cart', verbose_name='Корзина', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="related_products")
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, verbose_name='Товар', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qty = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    final_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Общая цена')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Продукт: {} (для корзины)".format(self.product.title)


class Cart(models.Model):

    owner - models.ForeignKey('Customer', verbose_name='Владелец', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(CartProduct, blank=True, related_name="related_cart")
    total_products = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    final_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='Общая цена')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    class Customer(models.Model):

        user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Пользователь', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Номер телефона')
        address = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Адрес')

        def __str__(self):
            return "Покупатель: {} {}" .format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)



class Specification(models.Model):

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Имя товара для характеристик")

     def __str__(self):
         return "Характеристики для товара: {}" .format(self.name)
```

ошибка
IndentationError: unexpected indent

я проверила ВСЕ отступы уже, ничего не помогает((

Answer (score 0):

У меня применились миграции стоило убрать лишь последний метод **str**, но в чём там проблема кроме лишнего пробела я понять не могу)

Comment: Там с отступом проблема. Пробел лишний перед def.

Comment: я тупанула и в "    owner - models.ForeignKey('Customer', verbose_name='Владелец', on_delete=models.CASCADE)"  стоит минус вместо =.    четыре часа сижу, глаз замылился,  только через пару часов заметила вообще